# Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have some strange error in PHPmyadmin.

> Warning in ./libraries/pmd_common.php#405  count(): Parameter must be
> an array or an object that implements Countable
>
> Backtrace
>
> ./db_designer.php#102: PMA_getLoadingPage(string 'DB_Name')

How to fix it?

Comment: Could you please tell us which PHP, phpMyAdmin, and MySQL/MariaDB versions you have?

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo nano +405 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/pmd_common.php and replace
`if (count($min_page_no[0])) {`
with
`if (count((array)$min_page_no[0])) {`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your answer to add information on why this solves the problem. This site is also about learning and simply responding with "this will solve it" is not as helpful as "this will solve it because x, y and z." Thanks!